# How do i use this php variable outside this function

Tags: php

```
<?php
    if (isset ($_POST['user_input'])&& !empty($_POST['user_input']))
    {
        echo $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
   }
?>

<br>
<hr>
<form action="51consoringWords.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name = "user_input" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If I want to use the variable with echo `$user_input`  outside the if function parenthesis it gives an undefined user_input error as well as if I try to embed php inside the html and use it to output the input typed by the user it gives the same undefined error. How do I solve this problem. I tried defining it as global $user_input but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Tested and works.

```
<?php 
 $user_input = NULL;

 if (isset ($_POST['user_input'])&& !empty($_POST['user_input']))
 {
    echo $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
 }

echo $user_input; 
?>

<br>
<hr>
<form action="51consoringWords.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name = "user_input" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It works..... Can you tell whats the use of having that condition  `if  (isset ($_POST['user_input'])&& !empty($_POST['user_input']))`  It works without that also by simply using echo `$user_input`

Comment: Great to see you are happy with it :-)

Comment: @hakas

Great to see you are happy with it :-)

Actually `if (isset ($_POST['user_input'])&& !empty($_POST['user_input']))` is used to test if there is a value assigned to the input field. 

`isset ($_POST['user_input'] ` checks if  `<textarea name = "user_input" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea> ` is set, actually both your codes do the same thing. Which is testing if there is a value assigned to the text area.

Hope I gave you a clear answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You declare variable above function and store data in variable and print outside of function.

```
<?php
    // First you declare user_input variable this way then use out side of function
    $user_input = "";
    if (isset ($_POST['user_input'])&& !empty($_POST['user_input']))
    {
        echo $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
   }

   echo $user_input; // output print here
?>
```